# Reading Files and Separators (python)

Tags: python, file

My current project is supposed to get inputted data and send it to a file, which will be later read to create a histogram. I can get the data sent the file well, however getting it back and organized is the hard part. So here's what I tried:

```
substringInt = 0
f = open("storedInfo", "r")
for i in f:  # searches line by line
    while i in f.read != ",":  # appends weights to list
        substringInt += 1
array.append(f.read(substringInt))
```

When I run it I receive this: 
`TypeError: argument of type 'builtin_function_or_method' is not iterable`

**I am a beginner at coding so if you could dumb down your answers for me, that'd be amazing. If my question doesn't make sense, feel free to ask me.**

Comment: Please repeat [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  Also see [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.

Comment: My apologies, I edited it, providing the error I receive. Does that suffice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python read file is not used in that way. You should write something like this:

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
  content = f.read()  # Read all the content in the file as a long string
arrays = content.split(',')  # Split the long string in to an array of strings with comma ','
```